# Determining if the value is a prime number or not in Assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, primes

Using this code or something better, I need to determine if the value is a prime number or not. The code does print out if it's a prime number, but I don't think it's working correctly because it does the same for a not_prime number. I tried to figure out the ISPRIME: but I can't find anything that will help.

```
.data
prompt BYTE " is a prime.",0
prompt1 BYTE " is not a prime.",0
Value DWORD ?
divisor DWORD ?

.code
main proc
    ; read a 32-bit unsigned decimal integer from the keyboard and return the value in EAX. 
     call ReadDec
    mov Value, eax

ISPRIME:
    mov ECX, EAX
    sub ECX, 2 ; excluding 1 and itself ; ecx as a loop counter
    mov divisor, 2 ; start the divisor 2

    
    ; a prime number is only divided by 1 and itself
    mov CL,2    ;CL used for the loop counters
    div CL      ; divides the value by CL and keeps the result's quotient in CL and remainder in CH.
    mov CL, AL  ; move AL to CL.

     
    ;
    ; write a 32-bit unsignedinteger to the console window in decimal format. Pass the integer in EAX. 
    mov eax, Value
    call WriteDec
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt
    call WriteString
    call Crlf ; advance the cursor to the beginning of the next line in the console window
    Invoke EXITprocess,0

not_prime:
    mov eax, Value
    call WriteDec
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt1
    call WriteString
    call Crlf ; advance the cursor to the beginning of the next line in the console window
    Invoke Exitprocess,0
main endp
end main
```

The expected output should be :

```
5

5 is a prime number.
```

OR

```
480

480 is not a prime number.
```

What am I doing wrong? Help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you understand that ‘cl’ and ‘ecx’ both map to the same register?

Comment: No, I wasn't aware. I am just now learning Assembly.

Comment: Okay cl is the lower 8 bits of cx, which in turn is the lower 16 bits of ecx. Same with the a, b, and d registers.

Comment: Does that mean I should change my CL's to ECX? I see I have it commented in the code that CL and ECX are both loop counters. Duh moment for me.

Comment: ISPRIME looks quite incomplete, it looks like it was started but abandoned. It needs more work.

Comment: cl is appropriate for an 8-byte value, but then you can’t be using ecx for something else at the same time.

Comment: I need help there President James K. Polk! I wasn't sure of where to go next.

Comment: Of course I meant to say 8-bit value there.